# Spring boot JspServlet autoconfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm running a Spring boot application inside a Tomcat (don't ask please :)) and I have some URLs that need to be mapped to /[a-z]*.jsp (again, customer requirement).

When running the application inside Tomcat, the JspServlet class is present and gets autoconfigured to handle everything ending in .jsp. How can I disable this autoconfiguration?

Thanks.

Comment: I highly doubt that the `JspServlet` from Spring Boot is configured when deploying to an existing tomcat. I would suspect that there is the actual `JspServlet` that is running inside your pre-configured `Tomcat`.

Comment: Hm. Where would that come from? I control every *.xml I can imagine

Comment: That is default started by tomcat. Also the `/*.jsp` mapping should be present by default. There is a global `server.xml` and/or  `web.xml` that is used to configure tomcat, which has that servlet and mapping enabled by default.

Comment: Yea the default web.xml is present, I found that one. I don't know why it's 'taking' the requests to /mycontext/test.jsp and not forwarding them to the application's DispatcherServlet though

Comment: Because that takes all `*.jsp` requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) said, the `JspServlet` is not being registered by my Spring Boot application but instead the default JspServlet present in Tomcat's default `web.xml` handles the request. Adding the following bean solved the problem for me:

```
@Autowired
private DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet;

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
    // Necessary so that JSPs don't get handled by the default JspServlet present in the default web.xml
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/", "*.jsp");
}
```

Additionally, I set

`server.servlet.jsp.registered=false`

in the `application.properties` although I'm not sure that's necessary.

Comment: The `server` properties are only applicable when using the embedded container, for an external container (like yours) they are useless.